# Neural Network Backpropagation Issue

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

I hope any of you are able to help me, I am working in a simple code of a neural network using backpropagation, I have seen many guides and I am still unable to get a fine result, when I train it many times I get Overflow error in python.

Before you see the code, the structure goes like this
*2 Input nodes
* 1 layer of hidden nodes, but a variable amount of them, the amount depends on the specific run.
* 1 output node
The final value should be or 0 or 1.

The input nodes point a list with all the Hidden nodes, also each one point a list with the respective weight for each hidden node.
BiasInitial. Its the Bias that comes from de input nodes to the hidden nodes, has a pointer to each hidden node and a weight for each one.

Each of the hidden nodes points to the final node and have the weight for it.

and the BiasFinal points to the final node with the respective weight.

```
def Training(X,Y,ElemClass,BiasHidden, BiasFinal):

k = 0
while k < len(X.next):
    net = X.out*X.weight[k] + Y.out*Y.weight[k] + BiasHidden.out*BiasHidden.weight[k] ### + BIAS
    X.next[k].out = 1/(1+math.exp(-net))
    k=k+1


# Net for final node
net = 0
for node in X.next:
    net = net + node.out*node.weight[0]
net = net + BiasFinal.out*BiasFinal.weight[0]
final = X.next[0].next

final.out = 1/(1+math.exp(-net))


#final error calculation
error = final.out*(1-final.out)*(ElemClass-final.out)


#alter hidden nodes weight
k = 0
BiasFinal.weight[0] = BiasFinal.weight[0] + error*BiasFinal.out
while k < len(X.next):
    node = X.next[k]

    node.weight[0] = node.weight[0] + error*node.out
    error2 = node.out*(1-node.out)*(node.weight[0]*error)


    #alter input nodes weight

    BiasHidden.weight[k] = BiasHidden.weight[k] + error2*BiasHidden.out
    X.weight[k] = X.weight[k] + error2*X.out
    Y.weight[k] = Y.weight[k] + error2*Y.out

    k = k+1

return (ElemClass-final.out)
```

I would apreciate if you guys find any mistakes, and if you dont I apreciate a solution for the overflow error.

Thanks.